# QGraphicsPixmapItem not showed in QGraphicsScene in deployed mode

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

With the following code, on my workstation (QtCreator an "manually" running) all works fine. But on an other pc with no Qt installation my application don't show the QGraphicsPixmapItem.

```
image = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap(urlFile));
image->setZValue(-5000.0);
scene->setSceneRect(QRectF(0, 0, image->pixmap().width() + 200, image->pixmap().height() + 200));
scene->addItem(image);
view->setMaximumWidth(image->pixmap().width() + 200);
view->setMaximumHeight(image->pixmap().height() + 200);

qreal centerX = (scene->width() / 2.0) - (image->pixmap().width() /2.0);
qreal centerY = (scene->height() / 2.0) - (image->pixmap().height() /2.0);;
image->setOffset(QPointF(centerX, centerY));
```

Do you know why ?

Answer (score 3):

I Know why :)

The folowing dll are needed to use jpg and gif : qgif4.dll, qjpeg4.dll.
In fact, a deployed application support by default, only the following formats : bmp, pbm, png, ppm, xbm, xpm.

The previously dll could be find in QTDIR/qt/plugins/imageformats/

To add the support of other image formats to your deployed application, create a imageformats/ directory on the same level of your executable and put your wanted dll in.